# Post a request with a form to an asp.net mvc route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

A third party site will do a request containing a form to this route (I will load its content like `xd.LoadXml(Request.Form["basket"]);`):

```
www.mysite.com/iPaperCheckout
```

Can you please tell me where I am wrong because it's telling me:

```
    The resource cannot be found.
Requested URL: /iPaperCheckout
```

I've registered my route for POST:

```
routes.MapLocalizedRoute("ShoppingCartIPaper",
                        "iPaperCheckout",
                        new { controller = "ShoppingCart", action = "IPaperCheckout" },
                        new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("POST") },
                        new[] { "Nop.Web.Controllers" });
```

I also added it in ShoppingCartController:

```
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    [HttpPost, ActionName("IPaperCheckout")]
    [FormValueRequired("basket")]
    public ActionResult IPaperCheckout(FormCollection form)
    {
         //code
     }
```

Do you see anything wrong from my side?

Comment: You can try to use Firefox Webconsole to track the direct url route

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't the url be something like `www.mysite.com/PaperCheckoutApp/iPaperCheckout`?

Using normal IIS + MVC conventions, `www.mysite.com/iPaperCheckout` would mean that the request is handled by an application called `iPaperCheckout`, and the application relative URL is an empty string. So by default the request would be handled by Home controller / Index action, if you have the defaults in you route map.

So I would guess, that your application isn't running where you expect it to run. Do you run it under full IIS? Have you created the application properly? Is the application pool (.NET4 required if you running MVC3) running?

Comment: Well, you were very close:) the issue was indeed the url...It should be `iPaperCheckout/` in my case.